# Make dnsmaq use broadcasted dns servers

Tags: networking, dns, dnsmasq

I am new to dnsmasq and am only using it because it is a hard dependency for other software I use.

I have configured dnsmasq to use Google's dns and it works fine, except when it doesn't. My college blocks all external dns and forces every device inside the network to use their internal dns server which breaks my configuration and forces me to hard-code their dns server into the dnsmasq config. This doesn't seem like a clean approach. Android and Windows devices seem to have no issue automatically determining what the preferred DNS server is and use it without any configuration.

How can I get the same experience with dnsmasq?

Comment: Your Android and Windows devices get the DNS server very likely from DHCP. It is very common to configure a static upstream DNS server in dnsmasq configuration.

Comment: @Thomas How do I do that?

Comment: By 'that', I mean getting the DNS via DHCP

Comment: Start by reading `man dnsmasq`, and inspecting `/usr/share/doc/dnsmasq-base/examples/dnsmasq.conf.example`